# Highstock grouping only H:M:S

Tags: highcharts

So, my data format just `H:M:S` without date so in X-axis only 24h. And this is what I have :
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRm9G.png)

My problem you can see on the picture. Data range almost 3 days. But all data accumulate in last 23-24 hours.It is because hour of the new day is not appear in the beginning of stock. What can I do to repair this ?

My script :

```
    $(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
useUTC: true,
            }
        });
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'values2.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   async : true,
        success: function(series) {
            chart.addSeries({name: 'Events', data: series[0], yAxis:0}, false); 
       chart.redraw();
        }, 
        cache: false
    });
}
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            type: 'column',
       shadow: false,
       animation: false,
            zoomType: 'xy',
            renderTo: 'container',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
title: {
                text: 'Events on ECAL',
                x: -20
            },                 
rangeSelector: {
enabled: false,
allButtonsEnabled: true,
buttons: [{
   type: 'hour',
   count: 1,
   text: '1 h'
}, {
   type: 'hour',
   count: 12,
   text: '12 h'
}, {
   type: 'day',
   count: 1,
   text: '1 day'
}, {
   type: 'all',
   text: 'all'
}],
buttonTheme: {
   width:60
        },
selected: 2
},
    tooltip: {
            xDateFormat: '%H-%M-%S',
            shared: true
           },     
     xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime',
      minTickInterval:100000,
       labels: {
        formatter: function() {
             return Highcharts.dateFormat("%H:%M:%S", this.value);
        }
       }
     },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 5,

   dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: true,
                units: [                       
                [
                    'hour',                     
                    [1]                           
                ]]
}
}
        },
        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Events',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: false
        }],
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'left',
            backgroundColor: '#DBFFDB',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 2,
            layout: 'vertical',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 0,
       x: 340,
       floating: true,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {

        },
        series: [
      ]
    });
});
```

And part of JSON file :

```
[[60866000,1],[60870000,1],[60886000,1],[60888000,1],[60893000,1],[60894000,1],[60897000,1],[60904000,1],[60905000,1],[60916000,1]]
```

Thank you

Comment: 1) your x value (first argument in each point) should be epoch time (time in miliseconds). 2) In the xAxis formatter you return H:M:S so why it should print other format than you declare? Add there a day display to confiugre other formula.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Maybe you don't understand me correct. I need to accumulate all data in one day. In this case 3 days in one day. First argument format is 1000*TIME_TO_SEC(`time`) where is 'time' have date format and TIME_TO_SEC converts H:M:S in seconds. So I always get only hours 1 January 1970. What you mean how can I display one day ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan ![Without dataGrouping](http://i.imgur.com/BMYlmHd.png)|
![With dataGrouping](http://i.imgur.com/UXL7SHA.png).
For example, without dataGrouping as you can see on screenshot I added 10 points ( 9 points one day and 1 point 3 days later at 11:30 ) So it works fine, but when I use dataGrouping this point ignored so this is my main problem.

Comment: Im confused, you have data from 3 days but you need to visualise in one day? It is strange.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Yes, all points must be in one day and accumulated

Comment: In the preprocessing set the same x value for each point and then init the chart.